# Does tapping an employee carrying supplies help or hurt in any way?

Tags: no-zombies-allowed

In No Zombies Allowed for iOS platforms, you can tap an employee while they're carrying supplies from the gate to their building of employment. It seems to take the box from them and they return back to the gate.

But the supply counter doesn't increase if you do this - nor does it increase if you allow them to reach their building. Is there any advantage or disadvantage to tapping them and relieving them of their supplies early?